# (C#) Create user control components with for loop and put those components in a list

Tags: c#, user-controls, components

Of course it's easy to use designer. But, in case for plenty of controls, it hurts to use designer. I'm trying to create a Sudoku table 9 x 9, and need 81 text box with exactly same size. I think, it will be easier to use for loop.

My code so far is like this:

```
class SudokuTable
{
    private List<List<TextBox>> table;

    public SudokuTable()
    {
        initializeComponent();
    }

    private void initializeComponent()
    {
        List<List<TextBox>> newTable = new List<List<TextBox>>();

        int sz = 30;
        int gap = 3;
        int x = gap, y = gap;

        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {

            x = gap;

            List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {
                System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(sz, sz);
                System.Drawing.Point location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                TextBox box = new TextBox();
                box.Location = location;
                box.Size = size;
                box.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                box.Font = font;
                box.MaxLength = 1;

                TextBoxes.Add(box);

                x += ((col + 1) % 3 == 0 && (col + 1) < 9) ? sz + gap : sz;
            }
            newTable.Add(TextBoxes);

            y += ((row + 1) % 3 == 0 && (row + 1) < 9) ? sz + gap : sz;
        }
        table = newTable;
    }

    public void addSudoku(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
    {
        form.SuspendLayout();
        foreach (List<TextBox> row in table)
        {
            foreach (TextBox col in row)
            {
                form.Controls.Add(col);
            }
        }
        form.PerformLayout();
    }
}
```

And add that table in Main Form with this code:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SudokuTable st = new SudokuTable();
        this.ClientSize = st.getSize();
        st.addSudoku(this);
    }
}
```

So far, it works fine. Here's the result:

[image]

My problem is, my SudokuTable class can't behave like normal user control. What I mean by normal user control is like when I create a user control via Project --> Add Class --> User Control. My class can't appear in the toolbox.

Is there anyway to create user control components with for loop and make it to behave like normal user control. So I can treat my created control like another control (like add it to Main Form with designer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to me you should create new UserControl and incapsulate all this logic in it. Then build solution and UserControl should apear in your toolbox.

Comment: It works. But, not perfectly. It did appear in MainForm designer. But, in SudokuTable designer, it give me error. The error said that the SudokuTable designer can't process the line where the for loop written.

Comment: i recomend you to remove SudokuTable class. You can implement all logic on your UserControl level. In other words combine UserControl and SudokuTable in one class. You can achieve this by inherit SudokuTable from UserControl.